# How can you gain weight quickly?

Tags: weightlifting

My nephew was 60 kilograms, 17 years old and 5 foot 6 inches tall six months ago.

He started weight training and now he weighs over 85 kilos.

Is this possible without steroids & peptides?

Comment: I have to clarify there is a huge difference etween steroids, which are artificial testosterone hormones, and dietary supplements as whey, creatine, fat burners... which are obtained from natural ingredients trough not worse methods than butter or vitamin supplements are.

Comment: Is he still 5'6"...?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is hard to say without a blood analysis, but if these 25 kg are muscle and not fat, and it has really been in 6 months... yes, he has taken steroids. And I would not say he has taken a little bit. Even if he would had win 5 kg I would say the same. 
Me, with 8 years of training, had won arround 10kg. I'm not into bodybuilding as a job, just as a hobby. I could have gained more weight maybe, but never ever so much as he did, always speaking of pure muscle weight.

Comment: Surely some of it is fat. If they're weight training on a calorie surplus, there is going to be some fat gain. It's not 15, it's 25 kg which is *insane* nonetheless. Either they're gaining fat (1kg a week is possible) or they're on something.

Comment: Already edited, I even hadn't substracted because when I saw 6x and 8x I had the answer clear, even from 60 to 70 it would be clear. But 25kg make me even doubt of the question itself, it seems almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible to accomplish this, but not if it's pure(mostly) muscle.

Keep in mind that they are still a teenager and as thus they are still developing and growing his body. A teenager can easily gain 5-10kg a year just through normal body growth.

The fat and muscle that they gain on top of this could in total add up to the 25kg. It depends on how much fat they have gained, gaining fat is far far easier, than gaining muscle. An average adult male can gain muscle at about a rate of 0.25 - 0.5 pounds per week. For a 6 month period that works out to about 6kg.

So assume they put on 5kg (a lot for a late teenager) from growth and they gain 6kg of muscles which again is quite a lot. That leaves 14kg unaccounted for which is possibly fat.

Does your nephew look like he has gained a lot of fat? 14kg in 6 months seems like a lot of fat and it definitely is not healthy however it is more than easily accomplished. That works out to less than 0.6kg a week which can be very easily done if a person's food intake is too high. Even 25kg in pure fat is believable in a 6 month period.

---

So to answer your question, yes it is possible to have gained 25kg in six months however the chances of gaining 25kg of muscle is impossible. Over the course of their lifetime, maybe but not six months. The other weight can possibly be attributed to fat. If you had measured their body fat percentage before and after you would be able to see how much was fat and how much was lean mass.

Comment: Unless his nephew hasgrown literally a lot, and has gained fat in an alarming rate like eating fast food for breakfast, lunch and dinner 7-days a week, it is not possible to gain 25 kg in 6 month. Maybe a teenager with growing problems (like these super tall people) and a tiroides affection, most probable thing is that he is on steroids.